# How to get full-size image from image field in PowerApps using IOrganizationService?

Tags: c#, powerapps

In PowerApps, let's say I have a field of "image" type called `foo_imagefield` on a table `foo_testtable`. I want to access the full size of this image in a plugin or console app using `IOrganizationService`. I can retrieve the record with the image field as follows:

```
string[] columns = { "foo_imagefield" };
Entity testRecord = Service.Retrieve("foo_testtable", new Guid("4B365AFD-B31C-EC11-B6E6-000D3A4EA781"), new ColumnSet(columns));
```

Now I can get the image bytes from the field:

```
byte[] imageBytes = testRecord.GetAttributeValue<byte[]>("foo_imagefield");
```

Great, except this only seems to give me the thumbnail version of the image (I believe PowerApps reduces it to 144px * 144px). It's super tiny. I know I can get the full version via a URL (e.g. https://myinstance.crm.dynamics.com/Image/download.aspx?Entity=foo_testtable&Attribute=foo_imagefield&Id=4b365afd-b31c-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4ea781&Timestamp=637801267356898020&Full=true as long as you are authenticated). I can also get the full version via rest API (e.g. `GET /api/data/v9.1/<entity-type(id)>/<image-attribute-name>/$value?size=full`). But being that I'm doing this in a plugin, I don't want to have to authenticate again.

**Is there any way to get the full image with Microsoft.CRM.SDK `IOrganizationService`?**

Answer (score 0):

From a Microsoft Sample to manage images, as a future quick reference to this problem. It returns automatically a full image. I have used to copy images from one environment to another one.

```
private static byte[] DownloadFile(IOrganizationService service,EntityReference entityReference, 
string fileAttributeName)
{

InitializeFileBlocksDownloadRequest initializeFileBlocksDownloadRequest = new InitializeFileBlocksDownloadRequest()
{
    Target = entityReference,
    FileAttributeName = fileAttributeName
};

var initializeFileBlocksDownloadResponse =
    (InitializeFileBlocksDownloadResponse)service.Execute(initializeFileBlocksDownloadRequest);

string fileContinuationToken = initializeFileBlocksDownloadResponse.FileContinuationToken;

long fileSizeInBytes = initializeFileBlocksDownloadResponse.FileSizeInBytes;

List<byte> fileBytes = new List<byte>((int)fileSizeInBytes);

long offset = 0;
long blockSizeDownload = 4 * 1024 * 1024; // 4 MB

// File size may be smaller than defined block size
if (fileSizeInBytes < blockSizeDownload)
{
    blockSizeDownload = fileSizeInBytes;
}

while (fileSizeInBytes > 0)
{
    // Prepare the request
    DownloadBlockRequest downLoadBlockRequest = new DownloadBlockRequest()
    {
        BlockLength = blockSizeDownload,
        FileContinuationToken = fileContinuationToken,
        Offset = offset
    };

    // Send the request
    var downloadBlockResponse = (DownloadBlockResponse)service.Execute(downLoadBlockRequest);

    // Add the block returned to the list
    fileBytes.AddRange(downloadBlockResponse.Data);

    // Subtract the amount downloaded,
    // which may make fileSizeInBytes < 0 and indicate
    // no further blocks to download
    fileSizeInBytes -= (int)blockSizeDownload;
    // Increment the offset to start at the beginning of the next block.
    offset += blockSizeDownload;
}

return fileBytes.ToArray();
}
```